# Laravel4.0 password reset is not working?

Tags: laravel-4

I am struck with strange issue.  I have implemented password reset functionality, **which was working fine**. **But few days after it suddenly stopped working because of no reason**. Not sure where is the problem is. Here is my password reset controller

```
class PasswordController extends  BaseController {

public function remind()
{
    return View::make('password.remind');
}

public function request()
{
    $credentials = array('email' => Input::get('email'));

    return Password::remind($credentials,function($message)
    {
        $message->subject('yyyy');

    });


}

public function reset($token)
{
    return View::make('password.reset')->with('token', $token);
}

public function update($token)
{
    $credentials = array(
        'email' => "xxx@gmail.com",
        'password' => Input::get('password'),
        'password_confirmation' =>  Input::get('password')
    );
    $credentials;
    return Password::reset($credentials, function($user, $password)
    {
        $user->password = Hash::make($password);

        $user->save();

        return Redirect::to('home');
    });


    }

}
```

Password::reset method does not throw any exception and closer function never called to save password. So it is becoming harder to debug for me. please let me know your thought on this

Thanks all

Comment: Do you have version control? What changed since then?

Comment: ya i have checked it, but there is no difference. but my source code is pushed to 2 remote branches, is that creates problm